# How to make "edit links" VBA code run faster?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I wrote some code to look for external links to "file A" and replace them with links to "file B". The code is in PowerPoint, "file A" and "file B" are both excel files. The PowerPoint file has about 25 "objects" linked to excel (the objects are primarily just cells from excel pasted into PowerPoint as linked objects).

The code works, but it takes 7-8 minutes to run. Any idea why it takes so long or how to make it faster? It seems as all it's doing is finding and replacing text, so I'm confused as to why it takes so much time.

Relevant portion of code:

```
Dim newPath As String
Dim templateHome As String
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim osld As Slide
Dim vizFile As Workbook
Dim vizFname As String
Dim replacethis As String
Dim replacewith As String


'3. Update links:
'(Replace links to template file link with links to new copy of the file)


replacethis = templateHome & vizFname
replacewith = newPath & "\" & vizFname
On Error Resume Next
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
   For Each oshp In osld.Shapes


     oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, replacethis, replacewith)
     oshp.LinkFormat.Update


    Next oshp
Next osld
```

Comment: oshp.LinkFormat.Update - delete this action? Because I think it is the main problem area. Otherwise, there will be every time such issues, because PowerPoint needs to scrap data from those excel files maybe

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line? You would find which line(s) take(s) the most of time.

Comment: Try `ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks` **outside** the `For Each` loop. This will update all links in the pp once instead of updating during each iteration

Comment: Is "File B" open?  If not PowerPoint will keep opening and closing it.  Open it (in code or manually) before you begin.  And if "File B" links to other files then all these will need to be opened too.

Comment: Dittoing what @Gareth said!! Open both `File A` and `File B` in code, _then_ start your relinking. It will _not_ be fast, but it will be quicker this way.

Answer (score 3):

This code is pretty clean, so there's probably not a lot you can do to optimize it, but I would caution you that it's doing more than just "finding and replacing text" :) Each call to `UpdateLink` retrieves data from some external source. That's not just simple string replacement!

Firstly: `On Error Resume Next` is swallowing a lot of errors (i.e., any shape that isn't a linked object, so, most of them), that's potentially increasing your runtime and *might* be better if you code around those errors rather than just eating them with `Resume Next`.

```
' On Error Resume Next ' ## Comment or remove this line :)
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, replacethis, replacewith)
            oshp.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Also, you're calling on the `oshp.LinkFormat.Update` repeatedly. It is probably better to do all your text replacing in the loop, but instead of updating individual links, update them all at once outside of the loop using the [`Presentation.UpdateLinks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.updatelinks) method:

```
' On Error Resume Next ' ## Comment or remove this line :)
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
        If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, replacethis, replacewith)
            ' ## REMOVE oshp.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
Next
' Now, update the entire presentation:
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
```

Comment: Big thumbs up on the `If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then` - saves a lot of effort trying to update objects that aren't linked.

Comment: Thank you! Trying these changes now

Comment: Is there a way to modify the IF statement to also run the code for charts? While most of the links are in OLE objects, there are also a small number of charts (which the code is ignoring).

Comment: Try maybe `If oshp.Type = MsoLinkedOLEObject Or oshp.Type = MsoChart`? You may need to add back the `On Error Resume Next`, but try it without that first and see if it causes any errors.